# Fullcalendar - refresh / rerender events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add and retrieve events using `fullcalendar` using Jquery UI Dialog and AJAX

I can add the event to my db, that isn't a problem. The problem is that this calendar will be used by multiple people at the same time, so I need to be able to add events and see others that were added (without refreshing the page).

I have the following in the dialog

```
buttons: {
    Save: function() {

          $.ajax({
            url: '/events.php',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(json) {
              console.log(json);
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
                 $.each(json, function(key, val) {
                   // can access the json data here

                  });
             }
          });

        $(this).dialog('close');

     },
     Cancel: function() {
     $(this).dialog('close');
     }
}
```

I'm displaying the events like the following way:

```
events:  function(start, end , callback){

  var events = [];
  var now = new Date();

  {%  for eventItem in events %}
    var evtstart = new Date({{ eventItem.due_date|date("Y") }}, {{ eventItem.due_date|date("m") }} -1, {{ eventItem.due_date|date("d") }}, now.getHours()+5, now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds(), now.getMilliseconds());

    events.push({
      title: '{{ eventItem.name }}',
      start: evtstart,
      end: evtstart,
      allDay: false,
      description : '{{ eventItem.description }}',
    });

  {% endfor %}

callback(events);
},
```

What I want to know is how I then get the items from the DB that have already been added and to display on my calendar?

Thanks

Comment: I have been dealing with fullcalendar myself, and the task you want is not a easy one, but addEventSource and removeEventSource is the way to go if you just need to add and remove events "on the fly" without refreshing fullcalendar. See the documentation.